# Sorting strings with numbers in Python

Tags: python, string, sorting

I have this string:

```
string = '9x3420aAbD8'
```

How can I turn string into:

```
'023489ADabx'
```

What function would I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the built-in function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort the string lexicographically. It takes in an iterable, sorts each element, then returns a sorted list. Per the documentation:

> `sorted(iterable[, key][, reverse])`
>
> Return a new sorted list from the items in *iterable*.

You can apply that like so:

```
>>> ''.join(sorted(string))
'023489ADabx'
```

Since `sorted` returns a list, like so:

```
>>> sorted(string)
['0', '2', '3', '4', '8', '9', 'A', 'D', 'a', 'b', 'x']
```

Just join them together to create the desired string.

Comment: This is the best and only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sorted()` function to sort the string, but this will return a list

```
sorted(string)
['0', '2', '3', '4', '8', '9', 'A', 'D', 'a', 'b', 'x']
```

to turn this back into a string you just have to join it, which is commonly done using `''.join()`

So, all together:

```
sorted_string = ''.join(sorted(string))
```